# Render html from sql - webmatrix

Tags: c#, sql, razor, webmatrix

I'm using cshtml pages with webmatrix, i'm trying to render the html that is stored in my db, but the output is like `<b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </b>` instead of **Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.** (This is just an example to explain what is happening)

I'm storing in `ntext` datatype.

Here is me code.

```
  @{
   var db = Database.Open("myDB");
   var selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM noticias ORDER BY id";
   }
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
      <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <title></title>
          <style>
           p {color: #f00;}
         </style>
     </head>
     <body>

        @foreach(var row in db.Query(selectQueryString)){

               <p>@row.header</p>
               <p>@row.description</p>

       }

    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: write into controller for retrieve data from db and pass as model into view, better create a DAO class and use the DAO class into controller. Follow best practices, follow http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: @JahirulIslamBhuiyan This is ASP.NET Web Pages, not MVC. There is no controller or model. http://www.asp.net/web-pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax with '@' automatically applies encoding of HTML sensitive characters. If your variables (or method call, etc.) returns a string that contains HTML markup and you want the browser to render that markup, wrap the string in a MvcHtmlString.

Any of these will work:

```
@Html.Raw(row.header)
@(new MvcHtmlString(row.header))
@MvcHtmlString.Create(row.header)
```

Note that this will expose the browser to ANY HTML markup contained in the values. This method should only be used if the data is verified to only contain safe markup, no scripts, etc.

Comment: Ok i see your point but i can't figure it to my example. And yes the data will have no scripts.

Comment: Nevermind mate, was looking to the wrong side. It's workin with @Html.Raw, just had to change my code and now it's working. 

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: `MvcHtmlString` is not available in the Web Pages framework. `Html.Raw` is the correct option.